# Get value of all radio button answer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

Hi I am mapping a set of arrays and displaying it, I have multiple yes or no questions

```
radio_props = [
  { label: "YES", value: item.choice[0]},      
  { label: "NO", value: item.choice[1] },
]

<View key={i}>
    <Text >{item.question}</Text>
    <View>
     <RadioForm
       radio_props={radio_props}
       initial={0}
       onPress={(value) => {}}
     />
    </View>
</View>
```

How do I get all the values of each question that I have chosen to submit?

```
 <Button
  onPress={onPress}
  text="Submit"
 />
```

Comment: Can u add few more code to understand. Code in RadioForm component

Comment: @CarloBarrogo - Check out my answer below, I hope that is what you looking for, or else you need to add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a `State` variable to handle whether or not the radio button has been pressed. You could create something like `isPressed` and in your `onPress` you could do something like this:

```
onPress{() => {
    isPressed = !isPressed;
    if (isPressed) {
        { label: "YES", value: item.choice[0] }
    } else {
        { label: "NO", value: item.choice[1] }
    }
}}
```